# Trigger golang lambda func in docker from SQS event

Tags: go, serverless, serverless-offline

I'm unable to start a SQS event lambda consumer on event when the serverless is launched offline with `useDocker` option. If I don't run the functions in docker containers that handler is triggered successfully.  I'm using the example from here (I'm not the author) https://github.com/alexyklu/serverless-offline-lambda-with-sqs. Bumped the deps in the repo to the following:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-domain-manager": "2.6.5",
    "serverless-offline": "8.2.0",
    "serverless-offline-sqs": "5.0.0"
  }
```

and had to update the runtime to `runtime: nodejs12.x` . Launching it like that:

```sh
 sls offline start --stage local --useDocker
```

I'm forced to use the docker approach because my handler is a golang function and as far I  understand there is no other way to use golang other than using docker. Any workaround to any of the problems?

I've posted the above as an issue in the sqs offline plugin but to be honest I'm unsure if that's a problem with the plugin, the general offline plugin, or me.